# Shopify Max Quantity Selector

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

Good morning, I've been doing some research online and can't seem to find any answers. I'm creating a Shopify web application, and my goal is to disable the add incrementer when the quantity value is equal to the stock value. Aka, not allow the the customer to order more than what we have in stock.

Here is a solution that I tried, maybe you could help me understand what I need to do. I'm very new to shopify so I'm still learning.

```
              <div id="qv-quantity-selector" class="product-form__input product-form__quantity">
            <quantity-input class="quantity">
              <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="minus" type="button">
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.quantity.decrease' | t: product: product.title | escape }}</span>
               {% include 'icons' with 'minus' %}
              </button>
              <input type="number" id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="current_variant.inventory_quantity == 1" class="product-form__input product-form__input--quantity" data-quantity-input>
              <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="plus" type="button">
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.quantity.increase' | t: product: product.title | escape }}</span>
                 {% include 'icons' with 'plus' %}
              </button>
            </quantity-input>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After More research, I did find a solution that worked. If anyone else runs into this issue I'd highly recommend checking out this resource as it worked for me.

https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/limit-quantity-selector/m-p/606554#M151983